# How to store itertools.chain and use it more than once?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I would like to use `itertools.chain` for efficient concatenation of lists (memoization), but I need to be able to read (or `map`, etc.) the result multiple times. This example illustrates the problem:

```
import itertools
a = itertools.chain([1, 2], [3, 4])
print list(a) # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
print list(a) # => []
```

What is the best way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As with all generators, you'll need to convert it to a list and store that result instead:

```
a = list(a)
```

This is a fundamental principle of generators, they are expected to produce their sequence only *once*.

Moreover, you cannot simply store a generator for memoization purposes, as the underlying lists *could change*. In almost all memoization use-cases, you should store the list instead; a generator is usually only a means of efficiently transforming or filtering the underlying sequences, and does not represent the data you want to memoize itself. It's as if you are storing a function, not it's output. In your specific case, if all what you are doing is using `chain()` to concatenate existing lists, *store those lists directly* instead.

Note that this enables generators to produce endless sequences, so be careful with that you convert to a list.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Sounds like I should just concatenate the lists. Is there a more efficient way to do so than `list1 + list2 + ...`?

Comment: @jtbandes: You could use `timeit` to compare `list(chain())` with `list1 + ..`, but I *suspect* the latter is going to be the most efficient.

Answer (score 4):

Try [itertools.tee](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee):

```
import itertools
a = itertools.chain([1, 2], [3, 4])
a, b = itertools.tee(a)
print list(b) # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
a, b = itertools.tee(a)
print list(b) # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that memoizing a generator is useless, really.

Comment: From the docs: In general, if one iterator uses most or all of the data before another iterator starts, it is faster to use `list()` instead of `tee()`.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti: note that the poster didn't ask what is faster or better, their question is how to reuse a generator, and itertools.tee provides exactly that.

Comment: @thg435 My comment is more of a note for others who might come across the question